# How to add space at vertex in `feynmp`

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

Is there a way to reproduce the following Feynman-diagrams using the 'feynmp' package?
[image]

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{loop_2}
  \begin{align*} 
  \fmfframe(2,12.5)(2,-12.5){%
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1}
        \fmf{fermion}{v2,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{v2,o2}
        \fmf{fermion,left}{v1,v2}
        \fmf{fermion,right}{v1,v2}
      \end{fmfgraph*}%
  }
  +
  \fmfframe(2,12.5)(2,-12.5){%
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \fmf{fermion,left}{v1,v2,v1}
      \end{fmfgraph*}%
  }
  \end{align*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

which are supposed to be the first and third diagram from the first picture. I don't know of any option to add space at a vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you can tweak the positioning of the vertices; I believe introducing phantom lines is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{loop}
      \begin{fmfgraph}(100,60)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1d} \fmf{fermion,right}{v1d,v2d} \fmf{fermion}{v2d,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1u} \fmf{fermion,left}{v1u,v2u} \fmf{fermion}{v2u,o2}
        \fmf{phantom,tension=5}{v1u,v1d}
        \fmf{phantom,tension=5}{v2u,v2d}
      \end{fmfgraph}%
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I had to change the dimensions as your code didn't give me the output.)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!